# How to perform a similar action with the dot accessor scheme on object properties?

Tags: javascript

One of my friend had a discussion regarding this,

Consider:

```
var myString = new String("Hello world");
alert(myString["length"]); // 11

myString["simpleExample"] = true;
alert(myString.simpleExample); // true

myString["spaced Example"] = false;
alert(myString["spaced Example"]); // false
```

Taking all the properties into an array,

```
var props = ["length","simpleExample","spaced Example"];
```

now, this will,

```
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
alert(myString[props[i]]);
}
// alerts each property individually: 11 true false
```

This doesn't work,

```
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {

            alert(myString.props[i]);
}
// alerts each property individually: 11 true error/nothing
```

Is there any way to access those ***properties/keys(having spaces in them)*** by a dot notation or simply no for ***array ([ ]) operator*** is made solely for this?

***EDIT:***

The question was asked to my friend in an interview, and the interviewer hinted at a solution by using ***eval***, but I am unable to make out that thing.

Comment: Use alert(myString[props[i]]);

Comment: `or simply no for array ([ ]) operator is made solely for this` - exactly. Also for dynamic properties. Like `obj[someStr]` is not the same as `obj['someStr']`

Comment: myString has no property called `props`, so of course it wont work

Comment: @RameshKotha - that's **exactly** what is being done in the "now, this will" code, so he knows about that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @downvoter: Care to tell me what went wrong, for the question was asked to my friend in an interview, and the interviewer hinted at a solution by using eval, but I am unable to make out that thing.

Comment: If the solution is `eval`, I do not want to work for the company asking such questions. Yes, you can commit pretty much any atrocity using `eval`, but it's never the right answer to anything in practice.

Comment: @deceze: I know the pitfalls of it. But I just want to clear the air on how to achieve this.

Comment: @deceze: It happens sometimes what they ask you such questions, intentionally. Maybe he was clever enough to argue, had my friend responded with eval solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow yourself to use `eval` (which you really, really shouldn't for such a trivial reason), then it is indeed possible:

```
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    alert(eval("myString." + props[i]));
}
```

Putting it here only for argument's sake. Don't ever use this in production. And it still won't work with properties with disallowed characters in them (like `"spaced Example"`).

Comment: I did the same thing. In google chrome, it just didn't work out.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari As I wrote, it won't when properties contain spaces or other disallowed characters.

Answer (score -1):

`myString.props[i]` means something entirely different than `myString[props[i]]`. `myString.props[i]` is *the item with name/index `i` of the `props` property of `myString`.* Since `myString` (presumably) does not have a property `props`, this will result in an error.

The `myString[..]` notation allows you to get a property of `myString` using an *expression*, for example the expression `props[i]`. There is no way to do the same thing with dot notation. Dot notation is always literal. `myString.props` always refers to the `props` property of `myString` and nothing else.

Dot notation is also further limited to require property names which are valid variable names. E.g. `obj.0` does not work because `0` by itself is not a valid identifier; i.e. you could also not do `var 0`. Therefore you need to use `obj[0]`. Other than that, `obj.0` and `obj[0]` are entirely equivalent, but the `[]` subscript notation allows a wider range of expressions.

Comment: Please read the question carefully where props[i] corresponds to a string

Comment: @Akshay I don't know what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @Akshay The code as posted will not work because the syntax is flat out wrong and means something different than the OP is trying to achieve. The problem of spaces in keys isn't even relevant, if that's what you're trying to get at.